# System Restart after installing software

Tags: windows, restart

Why do some software require system `restart` in `windows` ?
Meanwhile , I have never encountered such situation in Linux based Distros.

Comment: Welcome to the world of windows ... Is there some reason you need to prevent this or just curiosity .. here's a good link on super user explaining possible reasons http://superuser.com/questions/171590/why-do-i-need-restart-computer-after-installing-new-software

Comment: curiosity I guess ,I was installing some software few minutes back and I had to close more than 10 application in order to do so.

Comment: @brendanmorrison You didn't actually include the link. OP, you should probably delete this question and check out [superuser](http://superuser.com/). If you can't find an existing post that answers your question, you can repost your question there and probably get much better answers.

Comment: @g4ur4v, you don't need to restart after every installation, you can cancel it, install something new, and then do a collective restart, I hope you might have tried that.

Comment: @michelle the links there Check it out, though I agree the question should be closed ... I would be interested in how linux kernel handle's install's differently to avoid restart's at all efore applications are fully installed and functional

Comment: @brendanmorrison, we need to restart linux too

Comment: @AnujKaithwas, Can you point out one such example ?

Comment: @g4ur4v, I was installing nmap on Backtrack, and it asked for a restart, also, whenever I update and upgrade it, I have to restart.

Comment: @AnujKaithwas this is true ... although it is much much less common , Aparently the reasoning is in linux where we can choose to just restart certain services windows just prompt user's to restart computer assuming they won't know how to restart a service

Comment: @brendanmorrison, but then again, if you know how to start/restart a service, that isn't much of a trouble. I assume where his mind is going, the stereotype that windows is primitive ;)

Comment: @AnujKaithwas No arguments here

Comment: @brendanmorrison, I don't know what that meant, or what he is trying to install, I have used some of the "power" software for Windows and have never restarted it on the demand of the PC, but only when I need to go to sleep. Nothing wrong happens.

Comment: You would think of restarting a service in windows if you know which service to restart,all you get on your screen is "Please restart your computer" .

Comment: @g4ur4v, well there might be a *cancel* button, right? or you can go to command prompt and stop the restart process if it has been automatically started by the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is innate to the way Windows was designed.  Loading an executable doesn't load the file into RAM.  Windows creates a memory-mapped file for the executable instead.  Chunks of the program get loaded into RAM on demand only as needed.  A page fault copies 4096 bytes from the file.  The RAM pages themselves are not backed by the paging file.  If RAM is needed for other processes then Windows simply unmaps the page and throws away the bytes it contains.  If the process again lands on the page then a page fault reloads RAM from the file.  Very efficient, this mattered a great deal when you need to run a 32-bit operating system and many processes in only 16 megabytes of RAM.  Still efficient today, but not as critical as it once was.

One side-effect of the memory-mapped file is that it puts a write lock on the file.  Necessary to prevent another processes from altering the executable.  That would be disastrous, RAM could contain a mix of old and new bytes in the file.  That's guaranteed to cause the program to malfunction.

Of course that makes the life harder for programs that intentionally want to change the executable.  Including the malicious variety btw.  So having to stop the processes that have the file loaded is required, it releases the write lock.  An update delivered through Windows Update tends to update executables that cannot easily be unloaded since they are part of the operating system.  Which is the reason they tend to require a reboot, the file is updated as part of the boot sequence when the machine restarts.

One way to bypass the lock is to *rename* the file.  The lock only protects the file data, not the directory entry.  You can then create a new directory entry with the same name as the old one.  And the next time the process gets started, it will use the new entry.  One minor complication is that you have to eventually delete the renamed file.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can think of is that some software requires services to be running for it to run properly. The restart likely adds these services to the ones that automatically run when you start the computer so that the program can run smoothly.

Comment: Cant we just start running the service that the installation needs ? Is this a good design where installing one software requires you to close ten other applications and restart the whole computer just to install one more.